# Android - Distinguish between events triggered by FileObserver when accessing file

Tags: android, fileobserver

In our  android app we need to be able to distinguish between when a file is accessed by an application such as 'Gallery' vs when that same application  opens the file.

Currently we are  using the file observer to monitor the events associated with a particular file.
What we are seeing is that  the events are not consistent  between OS versions or even between different file types related to accessing and opening files
For example

On Kitkat we are seeing that when the gallery (or other applications) list the images the following events are fired:

1. OPEN
2. ACCESS
3. CLOSE

When opening the file through gallery we see the following events:

1. OPEN
2. ACESS x n
3. CLOSE

ON Lollipop we see a different set of Events triggered on the open of an image through Gallery

1. OPEN
2. CLOSE
3. OPEN
4. CLOSE

The question is:
Is there a way to reliably determine whether a file is being accessed ( to be displayed in a list ) or whether a file is being opened

Comment: anyone? I just find it hard to believe no one has faced this issue before